# How to tell when image has been displayed in a view

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an Activity that displays a spinning ProgressBar while an image is being retrieved from a server in the background. Once the image is retrieved, it is displayed in the ImageView, which also hides the ProgressBar. Additionally, there are some menu items that perform various  operations on the image.

I don't want these menu items displayed until the image has been loaded into the ImageView. Is there some kind of listener that I can add to the ImageView to know when its image has been displayed? I tried adding onFocusListener to the ProgressBar to notify me when ProgressBar no longer has focus, thinking that it loses focus when the ImageView image is displayed, but it never got triggered. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What code is loading the image into the ImageView? Couldn't you enable the buttons from there?

Comment: Instead of adding a listener, a better solution would be adding a calling a function (eg: imageLoaded();) after the network code.

Comment: It's being loaded by an AsyncTask and there is no clear connection from the Activity that is displaying the image (waiting for it to be loaded) to the loading logic. The ImageView is one of the arguments to the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

for loading image you would be using some library or some imageloader class, check there after  all byte download library would be converting file bytes into bitmap to set in imageview, just before setting bitmap in ImageView you have to use there a callback interface to notify your menu items for take action for display.

for specific answer please post your image loading code.

if you using AndroidQuery then do it like below:

```
File file = new File(path);

//load image from file with callback
aq.id(R.id.avatar).image(file, false, 300, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){

    @Override
    public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status){

        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

        //do something with the bm

    }

});
```

Comment: I am not loading it using AndroidQuery, the ImageLoader is based on the sample code provided by Google. But as per your suggestion, I will try to look inside the loading code, just before the image is set, to see if I can do something from there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are asking is present in this library...

android-query-full.0.26.7.jar

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

i have used this in my project https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.ive

hope it will help u...

remember there is callback after the image has loaded plz go thru the tutorial it had been long time i used it hence i dont exactly remember but its there THE CALLBACK...

thx